# prevent moving text while click and move 'a href' tag inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have created an `iframe` and loaded a html page in it.
The page consists for links using `<a href=''>`. When I click and move over the links, the text begins moving along with mouse pointer.

[image: The link following my mouse]

Comment: Can you provide some code please?

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the parent page ? If not you will have [Same-Origin Policy issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: I dont want to load links in iframe. Need to prevent click and move causing issue for <a>. Any css to prevent this user-select:none not working for this links in mozila

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `draggable attribute` to `false`. By default `<a>` elements have `draggable="true"`. Of course you'll need access to the HTML, if you're calling external links not much you can do.
Like this:

```
<a draggable="false" href=''></a>
```